# Class diagramm for a client-server game

Tags: class, unity-game-engine, uml, client-server, class-diagram

I'm an university student and I'm trying to do a class diagramm for a very simple client-server game.

The game consist of a online rouge-like when 2 player explore a dungeon. I'm having trouble to identify an easy class diagramm. Should I show in the class diagramm the server class and the  client class? What other classes should I add?

Here is what I’ve done so far:  [image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. I have slightly edited your question, because on stack overflow questions must be very precise and focused. The classes being in Italian, it’s difficult for us to help. So I limited my own answer to the question in the narrative without any reference to the diagram.

Comment: For non-Italian this is not to read. So you have a couple of classes somehow connected. Might be right or wrong. Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to keep class diagrams small and focused on a given topic. This is true for simple games, as it is for complex  systems. This leads to have several diagrams that are easy to read rather than one big and extremely complex diagram with all possible classes of your system. It would therefore seem better to keep client and server classes separate in different diagrams.

In the special case of a client-server system, the client and the server might moreover have different designs targetting different technologies. This is one reason more to keep them separate, unless you intend to reuse the same design on both sides, for example if you intend to have a common code base with a rich client.

However, it could be very helpful to you, to use a component diagram, at a higher level than individual classes. Component diagrams allow to focus on the interfaces between the parts of your system and will allow to explain the big picture (e.g. that there is a client and a server and how they are interfaced) before diving into the details.